# Is it a type checker bug?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-safety

I narrowed it down to the following piece of code:

```
trait A[T] {
  def apply(t: T): Int
}

sealed trait P {
  def apply(): Int
}

case class I[T](a: A[T], t: T) extends P {
  def apply: Int = a(t)
}

case class X[T1, T2](a1: A[T1], a2: A[T2]) extends A[(T1, T2)] {
  def apply(t: (T1, T2)): Int =
    t match {
      case (t1, t2) => a1(t1) + a2(t2)
    }
}

object m {
  def apply(p1: P, p2: P): P =
    (p1, p2) match {
      case (I(a1, t1), I(a2, t2)) =>
        I(X(a1, a2), (t2, t1)) // <-- Here
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a type error in the line marked `<-- Here`. And yet, the code compiles without even a warning, and fails with `ClassCastException` at runtime. Code to play with:

```
case class E() extends A[Int] {
  def apply(t: Int): Int = t
}

case class S() extends A[String] {
  def apply(t: String): Int = t.length
}

object Test {
  def apply() = {
    val pe: P = I(E(), 3)
    val ps: P = I(S(), "abcd")
    val pp: P = m(pe, ps)
    pp()
  }
}
```

I know that when pattern-matching scala sometimes can't check that a value is of the right type, but that usually results in compiler warning.

So, is it a bug, or do I miss something?

*Update*: What I'm worried about is that I can make a type error and the compiler won't even warn me. I do understand that `(t1, t2)` is the correct order; but if I write it incorrectly, I won't discover it until executing the program, and maybe even later, although it's clearly a type error.

Comment: My guess: your pattern match in the line before the "error" line has the assigns the following types: `a1` and `a2` both are `A[Any]` and `t1` and `t2` both are `Any`. You should probably explicitly state the expected types.

Comment: @Conrad but see my example. I added similar code to that ticket, so hopefully they'll boost the warning. Personally, I find the semantics of pattern matching subtle, so I think it should warn when the code expresses an unproven match. I know people say that pattern matching means "no more type-safety for you!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the lack of warning is related to this one:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9188

It doesn't seem to do anything useful with the type parameter on A, unless it can prove statically that you got it wrong.

The last match here should warn:

```
scala> val i = I(E(), 42)
i: I[Int] = I(E(),42)

scala> i match { case I(a: A[Int], x) => }

scala> i match { case I(a: A[String], x) => }
<console>:15: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern A[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              i match { case I(a: A[String], x) => }
                                  ^
<console>:15: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : A[String]
 required: A[Int]
              i match { case I(a: A[String], x) => }
                                  ^

scala> (i: P) match { case I(a: A[String], x) => }
<console>:15: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern A[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              (i: P) match { case I(a: A[String], x) => }
                                       ^
<console>:15: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : A[String]
 required: A[Any]
Note: String <: Any, but trait A is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
              (i: P) match { case I(a: A[String], x) => }
                                       ^

scala> (i: P) match { case I(a: A[Int], x) => }
<console>:15: warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern A[Int] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              (i: P) match { case I(a: A[Int], x) => }
                                       ^
<console>:15: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : A[Int]
 required: A[Any]
Note: Int <: Any, but trait A is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
              (i: P) match { case I(a: A[Int], x) => }
                                       ^

scala> (i: P) match { case I(a: A[_], x) => }

scala> (i: P) match { case I(a: A[Any], x) => }
```

Just to add:

```
scala> (i: P) match { case I(a: A[Any], x) => a("foo") }
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
  at E.apply(<console>:33)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: Yeah, that might very well be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: type-erasure.

When you're matching on `(p1, p2)`, all you know about either type is that they are each `P`, which could be `I[T]`, but not necessary having the same `T`. If you were more explicit about using `I[T]`, you might get a type-erasure warning, but since you've bumped the type up to `P`, my guess is that the compiler doesn't even bother checking for the warning. Bug? Maybe. I'd call it more of a deficiency. In any case, since the type information of `T` is erased, the compiler will allow this.

If becomes a little more apparent if we change the parameter types of `m.apply` to `I[T]`, where `T` is the same for both `p1` and `p2`.

```
object m {
  def apply[T](p1: I[T], p2: I[T]): P =
    (p1, p2) match {
      case (I(a1, t1), I(a2, t2)) =>
        I(X(a1, a2), (t2, t1))
  }
}

val pe = I(E(), 3)
val ps = I(S(), "abcd")

m(pe, pe).apply // same underlying type, works
m(ps, ps).apply // same underlying type, works
m(pe, ps).apply // doesn't compile
```

Whether or not that's what you want in the end, I don't know.

Comment: No, I really want those `p1` and `p2` be applications of `I` to *different* types. So, yes, I can write it as

    `apply[T1,T2](p1: I[T1], p2: I[T2])`

but I really want it to be a function on `P`s.

Comment: But then you try to mix them where they are incompatible?